# (new Date('2012-12-01')).getMonth() === 10?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

`(new Date('2012-12-01')).getMonth()` is `10` instead of `11` (`getMonth` is 0-indexed). I've tested on Firefox, Chrome, and Node.js. Why does this happen?

Comment: It returned 11 (as expected) when I tried it in FF. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't know what to tell you. It happens in Chrome, Firefox, and Node.js for me.

Comment: My apologies; thank you for clarifying. I have formulated my answer below.

Comment: Do a `console.log(new Date('2012-12-01'))`. What is it?

Comment: @Bergi `"Fri Nov 30 2012 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"`... interesting.

Comment: @MindVirus: Then it is a timezone issue (at least in your browser, not sure of your node.js server timezone). Use [`.getUTCMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are experiencing a timezone issue. Your JS engine interprets the string as UTC, since it was no further specified. From the [specification of `Date.parse`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.2) (which is used by [`new Date`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.2)):

> The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format ([15.9.1.15](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

In your timezone, the datetime is `Nov 30 2012 19:00:00 GMT-0500` - in November. Use [`.getUTCMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) and you would get December. However, never trust `Date.parse`, every browser does it differently. So if you are not in a restricted environments like Node.js, you always should parse your string (e.g. with regex) and feed it to `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, date, …))`.

Comment: I agree that it is an overall better idea to rely upon construction of a Date object using discrete input than a parsing mechanism which may behave differently under varying circumstances.

Comment: Actually I think the spec is quite clear. Section 15.9.1.15 says: " The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”. " (so Chrome is correct, Firefox is wrong).

Comment: OK, correction. Looks like a [mistake in the ES5.1 spec](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112) - the intention was to match ISO-8601 where missing Z means local time (so Chrome matches ES5.1, Firefox & IE match ISO-8601)

Answer (score 2):

For [Firefox's case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), at least, [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) states that [date specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) must be separated by [Folding White Space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.3). Try `(new Date('2012 12 01')).getMonth();` Usage of `-` as a separator does not appear to be defined.

Comment: There is no spec stating that `new Date` would use RGC2822. Opera for example parses it correctly as `Sat Dec 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100`

Comment: I think  - IS defined... as the minus operator 12 - 01 is November.

Comment: My source for RFC2822 is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Looking at the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), it indicates [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Rather peculiar that there would be a subtraction occuring, if it was so.

Comment: Maybe the leading zero coerces it into an integer.

Comment: [the spec for JavaScript dates](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15) is a simplified ISO8601 format, and has nothing to do with RFC2822. Maybe FF falls back to a RFC2822-like date format, but I would not expect it to allow folding whitespaces (with comments!)

Answer (score 0):

The error is arising from prefixing the day 01 with 0. Not sure WHY this is, but if you remove the zero before the 1, it gives you the right month (11).

Also, it starts giving the wrong month at October if that means anything.

Short term fix, use 1 instead of 01.

Comment: Not for me. I get `NaN`, not `11`.