# new Date() works differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I want to convert date string to `Date` by javascript, use this code:

```
var date = new Date('2013-02-27T17:00:00');
alert(date);
```

`'2013-02-27T17:00:00'` is UTC time in JSON object from server.

But the result of above code is different between Firefox and Chrome:

Firefox returns:

```
Wed Feb 27 2013 17:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
```

Chrome returns:

```
Thu Feb 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
```

It's different 1 day, the correct result I would expect is the result from Chrome.

Demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/xHtqa/2/

How can I fix this problem to get the same result from both?

Comment: Is that on the same computer?

Comment: @defaultlocale: the latest version  25.0.1364.97 m

Comment: @AaronDigulla: yes, firefox and chrome on the same laptop

Comment: for me in chrome it shows `Wed Feb 27 2013 22:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and in firefox `Wed Feb 27 2013 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: @Sandeep the main point is that Chrome adds timezone offset while Firefox doesn't

Comment: @CuongLe Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062863/firefox-new-date-from-string-constructs-time-in-local-time-zone?rq=1

Comment: It's `Date {Wed Feb 27 2013 17:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)}` for me in both (Linux).

Comment: possible duplicate of [(new Date('2012-12-01')).getMonth() === 10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311779/new-date2012-12-01-getmonth-10)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The correct format for UTC would be `2013-02-27T17:00:00Z` (Z is for Zulu Time). Append `Z` if not present to get correct UTC datetime string.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But there is an log saying, it will be deprecated in future !!!. Any Idea please?

Comment: thanks a lot, i've been sitting with this issue for two days, but this post solved everything.

Answer (score 31):

Yeah, unfortunately the date-parsing algorithms are implementation-dependent. From the [specification of `Date.parse`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.2) (which is used by [`new Date`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.2)):

> The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format ([15.9.1.15](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

To make the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) not (maybe) use the local timezone, use a datetime string with timezone information, e.g. `"2013-02-27T17:00:00Z"`. However, it is hard to find a format that is reliable parsed by every browser - the ISO format is not recognised by IE<8 (see [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802461/1048572)). Better, use a unix timestamp, i.e. milliseconds since [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or use a regular expression to break the string down in its parts and then feed those into [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

Comment: But the spec (15.9.1.15) actually says: "The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”" - so it should NOT be implementation dependent

Comment: OK, correction. Looks like a [mistake in the ES5.1 spec](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112) - the intention was to match ISO-8601 where missing Z means local time (so Chrome matches ES5.1, Firefox & IE match ISO-8601)

Comment: @sinelaw: Thanks for further investigating that point. However, regardless what the spec states, [old] browsers still are doing it differently :-)

Comment: @sinelaw: Can you add that to the answer? It's important

Comment: Oddly using Date.Parse vs. new Date fixed the issue I was having where Chrome would convert the date to the local time zone instead of treating it as already in the local time zone.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites—that's a bit weird as calling the Date constructor [*with a string*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) is supposed to be the same as using *Date.parse*.

Answer (score 4):

I found one thing here. It seems the native Firefox Inspector Console might have a bug:
If I run "new Date()" in the native Inspector, it shows a date with wrong timezone, GMT locale, but running the same command in the Firebug Extension Console, the date shown uses my correct timezone (GMT-3:00).

Answer (score -3):

Noticed that FireFox wasn't returning the same result as Chrome.  Looks like the format you use in kendo.toString for date makes a difference.

The last console result is what I needed:

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Try using moment.js. It goes very well and in similar fashion with all the browsers. comes with many formatting options. use moment('date').format("") instead of New Date('date')