# parse Date from string with locale timeshift js

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string: "2014-01-22T09:44:06"

I want to parse it to the same Date object. Here is what I do:

```
var dateString = "2014-01-22T09:44:06";
var myDate = Date.parse(dateString);
console.log(new Date(myDate));
```

Here is what i get:

```
 Wed Jan 22 2014 13:44:06 GMT+0400 (Московское время (зима))
```

Date object is 4 hours shifted compared to original string. How do I eliminate that shift?

Comment: Funny. MDN, claims that [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) assumes the local time zone if you don't set any. Accordingly, I cannot reproduce in Firefox. But the issue does happen in Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [new Date() works differently in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To get the timezone offset:**

You can use the function `getTimezoneOffset()` which returns your timezone offset in minutes:

```
var dateString = "2014-01-22T09:44:06";
var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
console.log(myDate);
console.log(myDate.getTimezoneOffset());
```

In your case this will output `240`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

---

**To get the UTC dateTime you can use following functions:**

```
getUTCDate()           Returns the day of the month, according to universal time (from 1-31)
getUTCDay()            Returns the day of the week, according to universal time (from 0-6)
getUTCFullYear()       Returns the year, according to universal time (four digits)
getUTCHours()          Returns the hour, according to universal time (from 0-23)
getUTCMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds, according to universal time (from 0-999)
getUTCMinutes()        Returns the minutes, according to universal time (from 0-59)
getUTCMonth()          Returns the month, according to universal time (from 0-11)
getUTCSeconds()        Returns the seconds, according to universal time (from 0-59)
toUTCString()          Converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time
```

In your case you can use simply the `toUTCString()` function:

```
var dateString = "2014-01-22T09:44:06";
var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
console.log(myDate);
console.log(myDate.toUTCString());
console.log(myDate.getTimezoneOffset());
```

Comment: I know about getTimezoneOffset - but how do I actually use it to get right Date object?

Comment: I want the pronted Date object to be Wed Jan 22 2014 09:44:06 GMT+0400 (Московское время (зима))

Comment: still dont get how to create right object.
Should it be somthng like new Date(myDate.getUTCFullYear(), etc..)?

Comment: TypeError: Object 1390383846000 has no method 'toUTCString'

Comment: @ProstoTrader sry, had a small error in my code, fixed it. Also you could add "Z" for "Zulu" which means "UTC" to your datetime string: `"2014-01-22T09:44:06Z"`

Comment: var dateString = "2014-01-22T09:44:06";
var myDate = Date.parse(dateString);
console.log(new Date( new Date(myDate).getUTCFullYear(), new Date(myDate).getUTCMonth(), new Date(myDate).getUTCDate(), new Date(myDate).getUTCHours(), new Date(myDate).getUTCMinutes(), new Date(myDate).getUTCSeconds()) );

Comment: @ProstoTrader did this work for you? Or do you still have pproblems?

Comment: finally I've used your solution - see decription below

Comment: i've deleted my answer because your myDate.toUTCString() actually does the same