# Safari Javascript Date() NaN Issue (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is working properly in Google Chrome, but not in Safari.

I figured out that I need to convert `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` to `ISO 8601`, but I didn't found a solution to do this.

---

Online Test Link: http://jsfiddle.net/UVgHR/

---

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    calculateMinutes();
    setInterval(calculateMinutes, 60000);

});

function calculateMinutes() {
    $('.calculateMinutes').each(function () {
        var diff = Math.abs(new Date( $(this).data('timestamp') ) - new Date());
        var minutes = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);
        $(this).html( minutes + ' min.' );
    });
}
```

HTML Example:

```
<span class="calculateMinutes" data-timestamp="2014-02-18 15:00:48">
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To make your question easier your problem is with:

```
new Date('2014-02-18 15:00:48')
```

This work okay in chrome but not in safari. The  mdn talks about [ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format support](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) says:

> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For
>   example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and
>   time) can be passed and parsed.

If you include `T` it works:

```
new Date('2014-02-18T15:00:48')
```

You can use `new Date('2014-02-18T15:00:48'.replace(/\s/, 'T'))`.

If you handle a lot of cases like this I will recommend using [**moment**](http://momentjs.com/) which seems to handle this case very well with or without T: [parsing from string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). Additionally your whole example is easier with momentjs:

```
var minutes = moment().diff("2014-02-18 15:00:48", 'minutes');
```

Comment: it is pretty handy utility indeed. I can't imagine working with dates in javascript without moment.

Comment: moment is great but it's also enormous. moment alone is almost 2x bigger than my entire app

Answer (score 13):

I think Jose missed one point here - Do not forget to include Z or else there will be lag of the timezone.

new Date('2014-02-18T15:00:48')
new Date('2014-02-18T15:00:48Z')

You can use `new Date('2014-02-18T15:00:48'.replace(/\s/, 'T')+'Z').`

Refer this for more info - [new Date() works differently in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox/15110304#15110304)

Comment: Please comment on Jose's answer, in stead of a new answer.

Comment: I can't comment unless it's my own answer.
Says - "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

:(

Comment: Noticed this issue in iOS and ended up here looking for the solution. Worked well for my needs (handled string replacement in PHP on a MySQL datetime value). Upvoting this answer since @AbhishekJain doesn't have the rep to comment, and upvoting José's answer as well ;)

Comment: This solution adds 5 hours in the date. Which is wrong implementation

Answer (score 5):

I've seen an issue like this before and what works for me is to replace the space between the Date and the Time with a `T`. Try this:

**Updated JavaScript:**

```
function calculateMinutes() {
    $('.calculateMinutes').each(function () {
        var timestamp = $(this).data('timestamp').replace(' ', 'T');
        var diff = Math.abs(new Date(timestamp) - new Date());
        var minutes = Math.floor((diff / 1000) / 60);
        $(this).html(minutes + ' min.');
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UVgHR/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Change this piece of code

```
new Date('2014-02-18 15:00:48')
```

To

```
new Date('2014-02-18 15:00:48'.replace(" ", "T"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in Safari if you replace the dashes with slashes:

`dateTimeString.replace(/-/g, '/')`

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing "-" to "/" may works.

TO

```
var myTime = new Date('03/09/2022 00:00:00');
```