# JS: Safari new Date().getTime() gives different results from Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I am doing:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

Chrome and Safari have different results.

How to make it work?

Plus, I want to get rid of this:

```
var n = new Date();
      var nYear = n.getFullYear();
      var nMonth = n.getMonth()+1;
      if (nMonth<10)
        nMonth = "0" + nMonth;
      var nDate = n.getDate();
      if (nDate<10)
        nDate = "0" + nDate;
      var date = nYear + "-" + nMonth + "-" + nDate;
      var nHours = n.getHours();
      if (nHours<10)
        nHours = "0" + nHours;
      var nMinutes = n.getMinutes();
      if (nMinutes<10)
        nMinutes = "0" + nMinutes;
      var startHour = nHours + ":" + nMinutes;
```

And turn it to something like this:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$startHour = date("H:i");
```

Comment: Mac new Sierra.

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427204/date-parsing-in-javascript-is-different-between-safari-and-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Safari Will be handling the date object some what differently from other browsers.When i face the issues, i tried something like in the code attached below and it worked well !

```
var dateSplit = data.event.start.date.split("-");
var date_instance = new Date(dateSplit[0], parseInt(dateSplit[1], 10) - 1, dateSplit[2]);

//where data.event.start.date  will be from a JSON like "2017-12-05"
```

Ref:[Invalid date in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari) and [Safari Javascript Date() NaN Issue (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883699/safari-javascript-date-nan-issue-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In this old post is the solution -> [Invalid date in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari)

> After looking at [datejs documentation](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/), using it, your problem should
>   be solved using code like this:
>
> ```
> var myDate1 = Date.parseExact("29-11-2010", "dd-MM-yyyy");
> var myDate2 = Date.parseExact("11-29-2010", "MM-dd-yyyy");
> var myDate3 = Date.parseExact("2010-11-29", "yyyy-MM-dd");
> var myDate4 = Date.parseExact("2010-29-11", "yyyy-dd-MM");
> ```