# Time shows as Nan on iPhone ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, date

I am not sure why my `time left` show as NaN when I view it on

## iPhone

[image]

## Mobile Simulator in Chrome showed working

[image]

I even tried an experiment the same code I use in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/7w8cftyL/

It's working there too!

## Does anyone else face this issue too?

---

## Code

```
<div class="timeLeft"></div>




function timeDiffCalc(dateFuture, dateNow) {
    let diffInMilliSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture - dateNow) / 1000;

    const days = Math.floor(diffInMilliSeconds / 86400);
    diffInMilliSeconds -= days * 86400;
    console.log('calculated days', days);

    const hours = Math.floor(diffInMilliSeconds / 3600) % 24;
    diffInMilliSeconds -= hours * 3600;
    console.log('calculated hours', hours);

    const minutes = Math.floor(diffInMilliSeconds / 60) % 60;
    diffInMilliSeconds -= minutes * 60;
    console.log('minutes', minutes);

    let difference = '';
    if (days > 0) {
        difference += (days === 1) ? `${days} day, ` : `${days} days, `;
    }

    difference += (hours === 0 || hours === 1) ? `${hours} hour, ` : `${hours} hours, `;

    difference += (minutes === 0 || hours === 1) ? `${minutes} minutes` : `${minutes} minutes`; 

    return difference;
}


var timeLeft = timeDiffCalc(new Date('2021-02-17 20:44:50'), new Date()); 
$('.timeLeft').text(timeLeft + " more...");
```

---

Comment: What if you run the code in desktop safari? Is it the same result there too?

Comment: Good call!, just visit this link https://www.bunlongheng.com/norden?code=l!ght on Safari, show `NaN` also.

Comment: I think the issue is with your date format when using `new Date(...)` which can cause an issue in Safari (I'm guessing you're using Safari on the iPhone). If so, have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883699/safari-javascript-date-nan-issue-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `T` as indicator of time right before the time as follow

```js
var timeLeft = timeDiffCalc(new Date('2021-02-17T20:44:50'), new Date());
```

You can see more date creation alternatives here in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#several_ways_to_create_a_date_object

**UPDATE:**

As per the author comment, the date is given dynamicaly. To insert the mentioned `T` you can use `string.replace` as follow:

```js
var dateStr = '2021-02-17 20:44:50';
dateStr = dateStr.replace(' ', 'T');
var timeLeft = timeDiffCalc(new Date(dateStr), new Date());
```

Comment: The time was dynamically insert. I don’t think I can add the T.

Comment: See the update @cyber8200

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). A simple parse function is 2 lines of code and works reliably.