# how to convert datetime to number in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to convert this type of datetime ***2021-07-05 17:41:22*** to time number ***1626351219837***

```js
let str_data = '2021-07-05 17:41:22';
let stringDate = new Date(str_data).getTime();

console.log(stringDate);
```

gave a result NaN

Comment: It works for me (on Chrome and Firefox, that is). The question is, what browser are you using it on? I know Safari has slightly different parsing behavior: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883699/safari-javascript-date-nan-issue-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss

Comment: `'2021-07-05 17:41:22'`  is not a spec compliant format. It very well might be rejected depending on the environment. You need a `T` between the date and time: `'2021-07-05T17:41:22'`. Do be ware that it will be interpreted as the local time zone.

Comment: your suggestion really helped me. i splitted the space, then created a new date array with the T included and it worked perfectly

Comment: To add, if you do want this in UTC time, you could also add a `Z`