# Is there a different in implementation of new Date() in JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datetime, datetime-format

Im trying to set a date time using new `Date(<dateTime>)`, but the behaviour is different in chrome and IE/Firefox.

Works fine for IE/Firefox but not for chrome:
`var date = new Date("2015-08-20T11:54");`

Works fine in Chrome but not in IE/Firefox:
`var date = new Date("2015-08-20 11:54 am");`

My questions:

1. What is the fundamental difference? is `Date()` implementation different in Chrome, IE/Firefox?
2. Is there a time format that is accepted by all the browsers when i use new `Date()`>

Comment: jQuery doesn't have its own implementation of Date()...

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: `var date = new Date("2015-08-20T11:54");` works in chrome, but there is a difference between `new Date("2015-08-20T11:54");` and `new Date("2015-08-20T11:54Z");` (note the trailing Z) in Firefox and IE, but no difference in chrome

Comment: Your first example works for me in Chrome: `var date = new Date("2015-08-20T11:54");`  It results in `Thu Aug 20 2015 04:54:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`

Comment: If you want to know what all ES5 compatible browsers support, you can read the Date object spec (section 15.9.1.15) here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf