# issue between browsers with date pad function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a date to a string and I am finding that my method works in firefox. But the same code comes up with a different and wrong time in both safari and chrome. I've put my code below. Can anyone see what might be wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var regLastSynchTime = new Date(item.date);
    regLastSynchTimeStr =  formattedTradingHourDateAndTime(regLastSynchTime);
});
var formattedTradingHourDateAndTime = function(date){         
    var d = pad(date.getDate());
    var m = pad(date.getMonth() + 1);
    var y = date.getFullYear(); 
    var h = pad(date.getHours());
    var mi = pad(date.getMinutes());
    var ss = pad(date.getSeconds());
    return  d + '/'+ m + '/'+y + ' ' + h + ':' + mi + ':' + ss;
}   

function pad(number) {
    return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
}
```

Firefox (right)
[image]

Safari (Wrong)
[image]

Comment: region/zone settings maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new Date() works differently in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was the issue