# Both Chrome and Node use V8, but give different result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

In **Node (v8.11.4)** both

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

and

```
console.log(new Date());
```

give the same result

```
2018-08-20T06:36:06.043Z
```

But in **Chrome**

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

yields

```
2018-08-20T06:38:53.118Z
```

and

```
console.log(new Date());
```

yields

```
Mon Aug 20 2018 12:09:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

As it is known that, both **chrome** and **node** uses **V8 JavaScript Engine**, then why they produce different result??

**Note:** I tested them on node v8.11.4

Comment: That's a `console` implementation discrepancy, not a Date one.

Comment: I guess you got the same question like this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122006/new-date-shows-differents-results-in-chrome-or-firefox?lq=1