# Date difference between two dates is different from firefox to chrome in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a case in which I get the difference between two dates, current date and previous date, the problem that the difference value between the dates is different between chrome and firefox, I checked, and the two dates have the same time zone, I'm not sure what is the problem, can anyone help me here??

for example:

```
  var current_date = new Date();
      current_date.setMinutes(current_date.getMinutes() + current_date.getTimezoneOffset());

  var previous_date = new Date(2016,9,20,12,45,00);
       previous_date .setMinutes(previous_date .getMinutes() + previous_date .getTimezoneOffset());

         var diff = current_date - previous_date;
```

The diff value here is different in chrome from firefox.

update:

the result for the upper script:

- on chrome returns the value 2481019194
- on firefox returns the value 2481000406

Thanks

Comment: Can you supply an example of this difference?

Comment: for avoid this problems you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: If you don't post the code involved, nobody can help you.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this similar question to see if this the issue you are running into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: I have just edited the post, and put a sample script from what I'm doing.

Comment: Getting the same result when I execute them in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: What's the `+ …_date.getTimezoneOffset()` about?

Comment: @Bergi this is to convert the time to the local time zone

Comment: @OmarTaha but the time already *is* in the local timezone? Just use `.toString()` instead of `.toUTCString()`

Comment: @Bergi That's true, I noticed that a little before, but also I got the same result

Comment: Again, what diff values are you getting? Please post them ([edit] your question)

Comment: @Bergi just added them

Comment: @OmarTaha Those don't appear to be different values. They just tell that you tried it in Chrome about 19 seconds after you tried it in Firefox.