# Create date from string differs in browser

Tags: javascript, momentjs

following example try to parse date from string (2016-03-27T02:00:00) using moment.js

http://jsfiddle.net/PAc3j/507/

```
var date = moment("2016-03-27T02:00:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss');
alert(date);
```

> Script executed on firefox gives 2016-03-27 01:00:00
>
> Script executed on chrome gives 2016-03-27 03:00:00

How to enforce moment to return the same date regardless of used browser?

I forgot to mention the context. String passed to moment constructor is user localtime. The date is special because in Europe at this time TimeZone is changed from UTC+1 to UTC+2. So in local time 2016-03-27 02:00:00 does not exists. Browser have to fallback to existing local date. I would like this date to be the same regardless of browser.

Comment: Is this on the same computer or different computers?

Comment: Tried in both and got same output `2016-03-27T02:00:00`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: Usually, this kind of errors is caused by different timezone settings. Try "2016-03-27T02:00:00Z" (UTC timezone), it should produce the same output

Answer (score 1):

It seems a timezone issue. Have you tried to set the utc timezone?

Right from Moment docs :

> If you wish to interact with the date as a UTC date, use moment.utc

```
moment.utc('2016-01-01T23:35:01');
```

This results in a date with a utc offset of `+0:00`

Or you could create the date fixing your timezone, if it's different from utc, like :

```
var date = moment("2016-03-27T02:00:00+02:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss');
```