# Javascript date parse produces wrong date

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, datetime, business-process-management

I am trying to parse the date to string that is input by a user using IBM's BPM Coach framework (input is in dd/MM/YYYY). I need parse the Date to String and pass it to an external service. I am getting desired results by using the following code snippet but for a few cases.

```js
var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();

    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    
    var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
    console.log(today)
```

While testing I provided the value on input say 01/01/1991, the javascript parser fails and the input captured is something like 32/12/1990.

I am not sure how to cater this. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you providing a value on input?

Comment: how are you providing this value `01/01/1991`,  the code above works fine

Comment: @JarekKulikowski Value could either be typed in or used through a date picker. It puts the date in dd/MM/YYYY

Comment: Perhaps this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox

Answer (score 0):

How would you call getDate() in this situation so it would return `32/12/1990`

```js
function getDate( inDate ) {
    var dd = inDate.getDate();
    var mm = inDate.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = inDate.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) dd= '0'+dd;
    if(mm<10) mm= '0'+mm;

    return dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
}

console.log( getDate( new Date()) );
```

Comment: Ok so i just ran another test run where i gave the value 01/01/1990 and when i see the parsed date in debugger it gave me upto milliseconds and the values that were given are as:

Comment: I don't know how you are calling it.  Perhaps adding some code showing the way you call it to the question would help.

Comment: Ok so i just ran another test run where i gave the value 01/01/1990 and when i see the parsed date in debugger it broke the date upto milliseconds and the values that were given are as: """
 `<fullYear>1989</fullYear>
    <month>11</month>
    <date>31</date>
    <dayOfWeek>1</dayOfWeek>
    <hours>19</hours>
    <minutes>0</minutes>
    <seconds>0</seconds>
    <milliseconds>0</milliseconds>`

Comment: @user3081780 Could you please edit your question and add this and any other relevant information to it, so people can reproduce the problem and find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may come down to what browser you are using. Chrome parses (correctly by most persuasions) dates differently from Firefox and Safari, and more generally, ["Yeah, unfortunately the date-parsing algorithms are implementation-dependent"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110385/2206251).

So what to do? You could try using [jQuery UI's](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) date picker and pass in the format you need, that way you can avoid the reformatting altogether and ensure that it works cross-browser.

Comment: I am working on IBM BPM where you could write javascript code in activities. So I dont know what is wrong with the date parser as when i see the date parsed in the debugger it gives me something like this. `<fullYear>1989</fullYear> <month>11</month> <date>31</date> <dayOfWeek>1</dayOfWeek> <hours>19</hours> <minutes>0</minutes> <seconds>0</seconds> <milliseconds>0</milliseconds>`