# Why does the Chrome V8 JavaScript engine recognize "TG-1" through "TG-12" as valid dates/times?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, datetime, iso

I implemented a CSV parser that guesses the type formats for each column but I have found that the JavaScript Date class believes "TG-1" is a valid date/time.

Is this some obscure date format I haven't seen before that Chrome supports? I wouldn't think this is a valid date and looking at different date ISO standards I haven't seen a reference to this.

Chrome 74 says it's valid.

Firefox 64 says it's not valid.

```js
let validDate = true;
try{
   d = new Date("TG-1");
   d.toISOString()
}catch(e){
   validDate = false
}
console.log(validDate);
```

Any string followed by `-` and a number 1-12 is considered valid:

```js
d = new Date("adsfadgag-12")//valid per V8
```

Comment: No exception is thrown when you attempt to make a  date with a nonsense string. You just get a Date object that doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like the constructor is ignoring your `TG` bit and seeing `1` as `Jan` for `2001`.

Comment: See what `console.log(d)` shows you.

Comment: Safari does not accept this either.

Comment: The "T" letter specify the following is time relative (cf ISO8601)

Comment: @Pointy It's an interesting question about Chrome's `Date` constructor.

Comment: @Nicolas it can be any arbitrary string followed by -
d = new Date("adsfadgag-12") is valid

Comment: @desean try looking at the Date object you get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110385/8188846

Comment: It is extremely easy to explore this fascinating behavior in the browser console. Just type `var d = new Date("any string you care to type"); console.log(d)` and you'll see pretty much the same thing for any string that's not any sort of date.

Comment: @desean you're really not reading these comments very closely.  The dates you're making **are not valid**.  You're expecting an exception that will **never** be thrown because that's not how the Date constructor behaves.

Comment: @Pointy I missed a line in my code. I updated it to correctly throw the exception

Comment: @desean ah OK, well the runtime is free to do whatever it wants with nonsense date strings. Firefox throws a `Range error` exception when you call `.toISOString()`.

Comment: @Pointy Chrome also throws an exception when it is invalid 

   d = new Date("TG1");
   d.toISOString();//throws exception

Comment: But `new Date("TG-1");` doesn't throw, it's a totally valid date in Chrome.

Comment: @Keith `d = new Date("adsfadgag-12")` // is also valid per V8

Comment: @desean right, and again, that's just what V8 does. The spec does not insist on any particular behavior when a Date is constructed from a non-ISO source string, so apparently V8 just makes something up.

Comment: Yes, it's just trying it best to make a date, if the number is > 31, it's assuming that number is a year, if the number is below 13, it will assume it's a month..  Anthing between 13 & 31, is invalid.

Comment: @Pointy I opened a bug on chrome. In my opinion  `d = new Date("NotAValidDate-1")` shouldn't be parsed as a valid date. I'm thinking they have a strange regex bug.

Comment: @desean no they don't. Thats not a bug, thats a (legacy) feature.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the [V8 sourcecode](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/dateparser-inl.h#L48):

> Legacy dates:
>
> **Any unrecognized word before the first number is ignored.**
>
> Parenthesized text is ignored.
>
> An unsigned number followed by ':' is a time value, and is added to the TimeComposer. A number followed by '::' adds a second zero as well. A number followed by '.' is also a time and must be followed by milliseconds.
>
> Any other number is a date component and is added to DayComposer. A month name (or really: any word having the same first three letters  as a month name) is recorded as a named month in the Day composer. A word recognizable as a time-zone is recorded as such, as is `(+|-)(hhmm|hh:)`.
>
> Legacy dates don't allow extra signs ('+' or '-') or umatched ')' after a number has been read (before the first number, any garbage is allowed).
>
> Intersection of the two: A string that matches both formats (e.g. 1970-01-01) will be parsed as an ES5 date-time string - which means it will default to UTC time-zone. That's unavoidable if following the ES5 specification.
>
> After a valid "T" has been read while scanning an ES5 datetime string, the input can no longer be a valid legacy date, since the "T" is a garbage string after a number has been read.

In other words: This behaviour is not really planned, it's just that some browsers behaved like this somewhen, and therefore this weird behaviour has to be kept. `Date(...)` will try to parse nearly anything without complaining.