# Javascript UTC timezone does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc

Below code doesn't work with Firefox, Works perfectly fine with Chrome. Can someone please help me to find an alternate solution?

```
const tempDate = getStartDate['startDate']; // Returns: 2020-08-13 12:52:38
new Date(`${tempDate} UTC`);

Expected Output: Thu Aug 13 2020 08:52:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: You have `GMT-0400` and `UTC` in there, which one is it? `new Date(\`Wed Aug 12 2020 18:34:35 GMT-0400\`);` works as expected for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [new Date() works differently in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do:

```
new Date('2020-08-13 12:52:38 UTC')
```

Instead you should do:

```
new Date('2020-08-13T12:52:38Z')
```

See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use moment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

```
var d = new Date(`Wed Aug 12 2020 18:34:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) UTC`);

var date = moment(d).utc().format()

console.log("date: ", date )
```