# timeStyle: "short" equivalent that works in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, time, localtime

I have a timestamp like this:

```
2021-07-23T23:35:00
```

When I try to format it as follows

```
var myDate = new Date("2021-07-23T23:35:00").toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeStyle: "short" }).toLowerCase();
```

Chrome will give me (correctly):

```
11:35 pm
```

IE11 gives me:

‎ `11‎:‎35‎:‎00‎ ‎pm`

Safari gives me:

```
07:35 pm
```

I've boiled it down to timeStyle: "short", but even after adjusting to:

```
hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'
```

Safari still gives me:

```
07:35 pm
```

Is there a way to get this with other toLocaleTimeString options?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a known issue, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17959660/14032355.  Try to pass ```new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)``` in this format instead of passing the string directly.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date.

Comment: You should really consider using an [ISO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) or [UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) timestamp to ensure the date is parsed correctly across timezones as well as both client and server side.